# Hashing a structure or similar data store in C.

Tags: c, struct, hash

How would one go about hashing a structure or similar data store in C?

I understand that this could be done in many OOP languages, though I am writing this project in C. I essentially need to implement a way where one can reproducibly hash the data that is stored in the structure. A good example of this would be a singular "block" in a blockchain, where the data in the block (timestamp, previous hash, proof, etc.) can be hashed. I have been stumped on this for quite a while and the only solution I have been able to think of would be outputting the data to a file and then hashing said file, though I feel like there could be a simpler and cleaner solution for this. This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow so forgive me if I screwed anything up, thank you.

Comment: I think it might be helpful to clarify whether you're trying to hash the struct itself, or a representation of the data inside it. The exact internal representations of structs are implementation-defined and could contain all kinds of padding for various reasons (mostly memory alignment). The first step is almost definitely to serialize the data somehow in a way that's well-defined.

Comment: I am trying to has the data inside of it, though not individually. So I guess hashing the structure would be the best, though I don't think the padding would interfere as long as the hash stays consistent. Security isn't much of a concern, I am making a proof of concept.

Comment: Would it be applicable to use a union and then hash that, over a struct? Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't the different variables inside of a union share the same memory address?

Comment: What kind of hash are you thinking of? Does it have to have the same hash value for same data on different architectures? Then the padding bytes and other compiler-specific attributes will trip you up. Endianess, negative representation, mantisse size, ... In short, I agree with @torstenvl in the case of cross-compiler communication.

Comment: Yes, im building kind of a chained hashing system. Where one block of info (the info consists of timestamp, previous hash, and index) gets hashes and then put on the next block's "previous hash" variable. Im starting to think outputting it to a file and using it as a buffer for the hash would be the most "simple" option here.